# Is there any online resource for mapping for province/states to cities?

Tags: resources

anyone have any idea?

Basically i need to have e.g.

when i select a province / state. A list of cities will be shown.

Is there any resources i can find for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[www.geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org) is a good free source of geographical data